# Resize Pie Chart Segments by user drag

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cocoapods, ios-charts

When a user selects a segment of a pie chart, how can one allow them to resize that segment by dragging the edge of the segment around the circle?

I don't just want the whole pie chart to rotate around the center. The segment itself actually needs to resize as they drag it around.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This sort of  "tell me how to <app feature>" question is not a good fit for this site. What you describe is likely to be pretty complicated unless the charts package you're using supports the feature.

Comment: This does not sound like something iOS-charts supports, so you are likely on your own to implement it. You'll need to attach a pan gesture recognizer to the view, then add code to interpret the drag gesture and change the values of the different pie "slices."

Comment: while you click on any segment in Pie chart it will resize automatically to  show its selected state.